# Third derivative vector calculus identity

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

So I would like to prove the following identity for a scalar $f$ and a vector $v$

$\left[\nabla^2\left(v\cdot \nabla\right)-\left(v\cdot \nabla\right)\nabla^2\right]f=0$

for the special case where

$\nabla\cdot v=0$ and $\nabla\times v=0$

and lets say we're in 3 dimensions.

I can re-write the identity I want to show as

$\nabla^2\left(A\cdot B\right)=\left( A\cdot \nabla\right)\left(\nabla\cdot B\right)$.

where

$B:=\nabla f$

and the same conditions hold now on $A$ as they did on $v$ and we now have te additional identity $\nabla\times B=0$.

It feels like this should be true, and indeed even seems trivial but I just cant get it to work.

I have tried many things but always end up with some cross terms involving first derivatives of $A$ in a product with first derivatives of $B$. These terms are of the form

$\left(\partial_x A_y\right)\left(\partial_y B_x\right)$ and 
 $\left(\partial_x A_x\right)\left(\partial_y B_y\right)$ etc.

I'm starting to wonder whether it might not be true.

Am I going crazy?

Comment: if $\nabla\cdot v=0$ then the first is obvious?

Comment: **Update**: I conducted a small numerical experiment on this by choosing a vector field $v$ satisfying the constraints and acting on a function $f$ I invented and, indeed, evaluating the left hand side of the identity does not yield 0 so it appears to not hold as an identity!

Comment: What I get (using the double dot product notation) is
$\nabla^{2}(A \cdot B) = (\nabla^{2}A) \cdot B + 2 (\nabla A) : (\nabla B) + A \cdot (\nabla^{2} B)$